# Spring Session - asynchronous call handling

Tags: spring, spring-session, spring-data-redis, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

Does Spring Session management take care of asynchronous calls?

Say that we have multiple controllers and each one is reading/writing different session attributes. Will there be a concurrency issue as the session object is entirely written/read to/from external servers and not the attributes alone?

We are facing such an issue that the attributes set from a controller are not present in the next read... this is an intermittent issue depending on the execution of other controllers in parallel.

When we use the session object from the container we never faced this issue... assuming that it is a direct attribute set/get happening right on to the session object in the memory.

Comment: Well, if asynchronous calls made so what will happen if first async request still not completed session creation task and in between that second async request comes which reads that session for an attribute

Answer (score 1):

The general use case for the session is storing some *user specific* data. If I am understanding your context correctly, your issue describes the scenario in which a user, while for example being authenticated from two devices (for example a PC and a phone - hence withing the bounds of the same session) is hitting your backend with requests so fast you face concurrency issues around reading and writing the session data.

This is not a common (and IMHO reasonable) scenario for the session, so projects such as `spring-data-redis` or `spring-data-gemfire` won't support it out of the box.

The good news is that spring-session was built with flexibility in mind, so you could of course achieve what you want. You could implement your own version of `SessionRepository` and manually synchronize (for example via Redis distributed locks) the relevant methods. But, before doing that, check your design and make sure you are using session for the right data storage job.

Answer (score 1):

This question is very similar in nature to your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497595/session-attributes-missing-intermittently-spring-session-pivotal-gemfire-imp).  And, you should read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52497595/session-attributes-missing-intermittently-spring-session-pivotal-gemfire-imp?answertab=oldest#tab-top) to that question before reading my response/comments here.

The previous answer (and insight) posted by the anonymous user is fairly accurate.

Anytime you have a highly concurrent (Web) application/environment where many different, simultaneous HTTP requests are coming in, accessing the same HTTP session, there is always a possibility for ***lost updates*** caused by ***race conditions*** between competing concurrent HTTP requests.  This is due to the very nature of a Servlet container (e.g. Apache Tomcat, or Eclipse Jetty) since each HTTP request is processed by, and in, a separate Thread.

Not only does the HTTP session object provided by the Servlet container need to be Thread-safe, but so too do all the application domain objects that your Web application puts into the HTTP session.  So, be mindful of this.

In addition, most HTTP session implementations, such as Apache Tomcat's, or even *Spring Session's* session implementations backed by different session management providers (e.g. *Spring Session Data Redis*, or *Spring Session Data GemFire*) make extensive use of "deltas" to send only the changes (or differences) to the Session state, there by minimizing the chance of *lost updates* due to *race conditions*.

For instance, if the HTTP session currently has an attribute key/value of `1/A` and HTTP request 1 (processed by Thread 1) reads the HTTP session (with only `1/A`) and adds an attribute `2/B`, while another concurrent HTTP request 2 (processed by Thread 2) reads the same HTTP session, by session ID (seeing the same initial session state with `1/A`), and now wants to add `3/C`, then as Web application developers, we expect the end result and HTTP session state to be, after request 1 & 2 in Threads 1 & 2 complete, to include attributes: `[1/A, 2/B, 3/C]`.

However, if 2 (or even more) competing HTTP requests are both modifying say HTTP sessoin attribute `1/A` and HTTP request/Thread 1 wants to set the attribute to `1/B` and the competing HTTP request/Thread 2 wants to set the same attribute to `1/C` then who wins?

Well, it turns out, last 1 wins, or rather, the last Thread to write the HTTP session state wins and the result could either be `1/B` or `1/C`, which is indeterminate and subject to the vagaries of scheduling, network latency, load, etc, etc.  In fact, it is nearly impossible to reason which one will happen, much less always happen.

While our anonymous user provided some context with, say, a user using multiple devices (a Web browser and perhaps a mobile device... smart phone or tablet) concurrently, reproducing this sort of error with a single user, even multiple users would not be impossible, but very improbable.

But, if we think about this in a production context, where you might have, say, several hundred Web application instances, spread across multiple physical machines, or VMs, or container, etc, load balanced by some network load balancer/appliance, and then throw in the fact that many Web applications today are "single page apps", highly sophisticated non-dumb (no longer thin) but thick clients with JavaScript and AJAX calls, then we begin the understand that this scenario is much more likely, especially in a highly loaded Web application; think Amazon or Facebook.  Not only many concurrent users, but many concurrent requests by a single user given all the dynamic, asynchronous calls that a Web application can make.

Still, as our anonymous user pointed out, this does not excuse the Web application developer from responsibly designing and coding our Web application.

In general, I would say the HTTP session should only be used to track very minimal (i.e. in quantity) and necessary information to maintain a good user experience and preserve the proper interaction between the user and the application as the user transitions through different parts or phases of the Web app, like tracking preferences or items (in a shopping cart).  In general, the HTTP session should not be used to store "transactional" data.  To due so is to get yourself into trouble.  The HTTP session should be primarily a read heavy data structure (rather than write heavy), particularly because the HTTP session can be and most likely will be accessed from multiple Threads.

Of course, different backing data stores (like Redis, and even GemFire) provide locking mechanisms.  GemFire even provides cache level transactions, which is very heavy and arguable not appropriate when processing Web interactions managed in and by an HTTP session object (not to be confused with transactions).  Even locking is going to introduce serious contention and latency to the application.

Anyway, all of this is to say that you very much need to be conscious of the interactions and data access patterns, otherwise you will find yourself in hot water, so be careful, always!

Food for thought!